# Using / to create a simple rational number object

Tags: c++, class

I have a bunch of data in the form of extremely long equations that includes rational numbers in the form of `(a/b)` where a and b are integers. I made a simple class that stores rational numbers with corresponding arithmetic operators.

I'm trying to write some code that is able to recognize the form  `(a/b)` and construct an instance of that class with the corresponding numerator and denominator. I would much prefer to conserve the original form of input `(a/b)`. Is it possible to overload the / operator such that `(a/b)` will return a rational number object? (If not, any ideas for a workaround?)

Example piece of very simplified code:

```
Param A;
Param B;
(3/5)*A*A + (1/3)*B*B
```

My Param class has a well-defined multiplication with itself and with the rational number class. I just need the code to recognise `(3/5)` and `(1/3)` as instances of a rational number.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're actually asking. Do you  know about operator overloading? If so, are you facing a specific issue?

Comment: Hopefully my comment on Matthieu M.'s answer makes it more clear.

Comment: Then please [edit] that clarification into your question.

Comment: @RobVerheyen even in your edit, it didn't explain _why_ you are trying to avoid changing your input. Since we _did_ explain to you that you really cannot rewrite a `Rational operator/(int, int)`, and as you asked for workarounds (some of which Matthieu gave you), ... what else can we do for you?

Comment: Well, for instance, I just tried if it is possible to overload some other operator, such that I would be able to replace every / with that operator, but it doesn't seem like that it possible either. I also just read your other comment, and I was completely unaware that you can tell an editor to do as you describe.

Comment: See my other suggestion: you can substitute each `/` for `*Rat/` and define `static const rational Rat(1,1)` on a header and you'll be ok :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; you can only overload operators if at least one operand is a user-defined type. You can't overload `operator/` where both operands are `int` or any other built-in type.

The closest you can get is `rational(a)/b`. Whether or not that's better than `rational(a,b)` is up to your aesthetic judgement.

In C++11 or later, you could muck around with user-defined literals and write things like `3_r/4`; but I wouldn't.

Comment: Changing the shape of the input is something I'm trying to avoid. I edited my question to better reflect my problem.

Comment: @RobVerheyen: Sorry, there's no way for `(3/5)` to be interpreted as anything other than integer division.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't write `Rational operator/(int, int)`. Because you can't redefine `/` for ints.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is no: operator overload requires at least one user-defined type (otherwise, they would clash with existing operators).

As for workarounds, there are plenty available:

- you may use a function: `rational(a, b)`
- you may use a proxy object: `MyInt(a) / MyInt(b)`, this introduces a user-defined type so you can overload the operator `/` on that type
- you may use the C++11 user-defined literals to wrap integers into a proxy class, and overload the operator `/` on that: `1_i` and `Rational operator/(MyInt, MyInt)`

Which solution you use will depend on the specific constraints you have.

Comment: The problem with these options is that they require me to change my data, which I can't really do easily. I could change all instances of a / with some other character(s), but I can't easily replace every instance of a/b by rational(a,b).

Comment: @RobVerheyen: Can you replace the type of `a` as `MyInt` ? If you provide a default constructor from `int` it should be relatively painless. Of course, then you will have to define all the operators you used with `int` for `MyInt`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I edited my question to clarify my problem.

Comment: @RobVerheyen why is it so difficult to do the vim-equivalent-on-your-editor of `:argdo %s|(\s*\(\d+\)\s*/\s*\(\d+\)\s*)|rational(\1, \2)|g` ??

Comment: @MatthieuM. even without C++11, he can use a `static const Rat(1,1);` and substitute all divisions on his input with something like `s|/|*Rat/|g`...